# Copying million rows of data from one database to another on laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Using Laravel Eloquent, i'm copying 7Million rows of data from one table on my old Mysql database  and putting these rows on different tables on my new Mysql database. The problem is that it took almost one day to perform this and i need to re-perform this action for almost 80M of rows. I'm using chunk of 1000 data at a time. Is there any way to do it 
more efficiently??
Here my code:

```
   DB::connection('oldDataBase')->table('tableToCopy')->chunk(1000, function ($AllData){
        foreach ($AllData as $Data){
            DB::connection('newDataBase')->table('table1')->insert(
                [
                    column1 => $Data->columnToCopy,
                    etc..
                ]);


           DB::connection('newDataBase')->table('table2')->insert(
                [
                    column1 => $Data->columnToCopy,
                    etc..
                ]);
           DB::connection('newDataBase')->table('table3')->insert(
                [
                    column1 => $Data->columnToCopy,
                    etc..
                ]);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If this is just a one-off copy, it is probably better to do it as an sqldump and then run the output script against the new db

Comment: Don't do it via laravel. Laravel does the query then does conversion to collections of objects, overheads that will definately add up. Do `mysqldump | mysql -e` or `mysqldbcopy` or even simpler `create table like othertable` and `insert into table select from other table`

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, i will do it like you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this data migration from a SQL client like laravel is not a good idea.

If I had to move 80M rows, I'd take the following steps:

1. dump them in CSV form.
2. split the CSV files into chunks of something like 500K rows each.
3. create tables on the target system
4. disable all constraints and indexes on the target system.
5. [use `LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to slurp up the CSV files one after the other. For fastest results this should be run from the `mysql` or [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) command line client program running on the *same machine as the MySQL server*.
6. re-enable the constraints and build the indexes.

I'd test this extensively before the migration day. I'd do things like load the first and last chunk of CSV and re-enable indexes and constraints.

Another possibility was suggested in a comment. Use `mysqldump`, then load the resulting file via the `mysql` client program.

Avoid the use of a gui-style mysql client program for this. Stick with the command-line programs. As good as those GUI clients are, they aren't engineered for streaming in multi-tens-of-megabyte .SQL files.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to that.

Comment: to handle and import CSV file is just a nightmare