# best approach to fetch data from old db structure, fix data with php and upload to new schema

Tags: php, mysqli

We have created a new db schema for old application, which currently has 4375987 rows in a single table with multiple columns. i have to migrate old data to new db schema which will fetch data from one table and be going to insert in multiple db tables. 
i need to know the best approaches. should i right down the script in PHP or and other solution. the old db has very large data.

please guide thanks.

Comment: _Best Approach_ Is to write something and see if it works. You are only going to do this once so as long as it works, who cares if its super slick or polished. _Or are you really saying,  I dont know how to do this, can you do it for me_

Comment: no no has to do again and again . has to verify with team about the data. i dont want to hang my production server. i want to have a best solution.

Comment: Why would a simple query on the production server cause it any problems

Comment: Seeing your reputation you should know better than to ask an opinion based, non-researched, examples and attempts free question. Please provide code, what you've tried, what went wrong, what you expect?

Comment: did you see the number of records 4375987 in a single table. do you know when we use the select query and on the same time insert, how much resources it uses? and time

Comment: There are a number of simple techniques you could employ, but as we have ZERO idea about the old schema or the new schema we can only make guesses

Comment: I assume you take regular backups of the live database. How about restoring the table in question to the new database and do all the conversion on the new database. Then you never even have to look at the live database

Comment: *no no has to do again and again . has to verify with team about the data. i dont want to hang my production server.* - get a dump, you don't test your code on a production server.

Comment: And what do your mean by ___has to verify with team about the data___

Comment: there are some problems in the old db schema that is why my team member hired me to create new db schema and now they are saying there are problems in old db data. that needs to be fix before we dump it into new

Comment: i am trying to elaborate with the best info i have. sorry and thanks for trying to help

Comment: is that solution make sense ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42012233/copying-million-rows-of-data-from-one-database-to-another-on-laravel

Answer (score -1):

Split your row up using a function. Then take each part of the returned result and do your inserts:

See https://3v4l.org/HEFS3

```
<?php

$old = [
    'name' => 'Dave',
    'dob' => '1970-01-01',
    'blah' => 'blah',
];

function convertRow($row) 
{
    $new = [
      'table1' => [
        'name' => $row['name'],
        'dob' => $row['dob'],
        ],  
      'table2' => [
           'blah' => $row['blah'],   
       ],
    ];
    return $new;
}

$data = convertRow($old);

// Now do your inserts
$firstTableData = $data['table1'];
$secondTableData = $data['table2'];

var_dump($firstTableData, $secondTableData);
```

This outputs:

```
array(2) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Dave" ["dob"]=> string(10) "1970-01-01" } 

array(1) { ["blah"]=> string(4) "blah" }
```

So you can now take that data and do your inserts for each table. Hopefully this should get you going! :-)